# Error with fragments in Android development

Tags: java, android-fragments

I am in the early stages of developing an app that will have a single activity with 4 fragments navigated by swiping. Currently all I'm trying to do is get the activity to load/display the first fragment Splash. I have added the fragment to the activity in the main.xml as shown below.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<fragment android:name="com.cdw.ddb.Splash"
android:id="@+id/splashfrag"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
    // the fragment_container FrameLayout
    if (findViewById(R.id.splashfrag) != null) {

        // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
        // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
        // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
       Splash fragment = new Splash();

        // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an
        // Intent, pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
        fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.splashfrag, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error:

Cannot resolve method 'add(int, com.cdw.ddb.Splash)'

on this line

.add(R.id.splashfrag, fragment)

From searching online it seems that the most common issues associated with this are not declaring "extends FragmentActivity" for the activity or using the incorrect import statement. I don't believe either of these is my issue. I would appreciate any guidance on the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the fragment classes from the support library, make sure your Splash class is extending the support library's Fragment class (android.support.v4.app.Fragment). Possibly you have imported android.app.Fragment instead.

Comment: The above answer solved the problem. I changed the line in the import section of my Splash.java from android.app.Fragment to android.support.v4.app.Fragment. Thank you.